# Irreducible finite Markov chain and its stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

Let $P$ be a stochastic matrix on a finite set $I$. Show that a distribution $\pi$ is invariant for $P$ if and only if $\pi(I-P+A)=a$, where $A=(a_{ij}:i,j\in I)$ with $a_{ij}=1$ for all $i$ and $j$, and $a=(a_i:i\in I)$ with $a_i=1$ for all $i$. Deduce that if $P$ is irreducible then $I-P+A$ is invertible.

My efforts:

$\pi(I-P+A)=a\iff\pi-\pi P+\pi A=a\iff\pi=\pi P$.

I have no idea about the invertible part.

Comment: $I$ also means identity matrix, in expressions like $I-P+A$?

Comment: @kimchilover Yes I think so.

Comment: I gave a simple proof of invertibility here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739163/proving-a-formula-for-the-stationary-distribution-of-a-finite-irreducible-markov/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Theorem** Every irreducible Markov chain with a finite state space is positive recurrent and thus has a stationary distribution (unique probability solution to $\pi=\pi P$).

Let $Q=I-P+A$. Then $Q^Tx=a^T$ has a unique solution $\pi^T$. So $Q^T$ is invertible.